# XMPP Room Chat Message

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I would execute an example to use OpenFire and XMPP with Java language:

```
public class TestXMPP {  

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {  

    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("127.0.0.1");  
    XMPPConnection xmppConnection = new XMPPConnection(config);  
    try {  
      xmppConnection.connect();  
      xmppConnection.login("serveur22", "serveur22");  
      Message msg = new Message("salon@conference.localhost/serveur22", Message.Type.normal); // Line 10  
      msg.setBody("Test Message TestXMPP.java");  
      xmppConnection.sendPacket(msg);  
      xmppConnection.disconnect();  
    } catch (XMPPException e) {  
      e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
  }  
}
```

I can send to a specific login but not for a room...

I think line 10 is not correct...

If you have a solution, thanks a lot

Comment: Which line is line 10? Please comment it to indicate it.

Comment: You mean you can send a message to another user, but not to a room?
If you use smack you can find here some examples: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/index.html

Comment: Yes, I have an error 406... or 404. I will see your documentation, thanks: )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your XMPP domain is localhost, as you have coded it, try removing the resource from the JID.

Change this:

**salon@conference.localhost/serveur22**

to

**salon@conference.localhost**